# filtering a promise iterated result array into a new array vue js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, promise, splice

How can I insert into a new arr  promise values of an old array. A splice method required due to vue reactivity. Somehow the newArray is empty and not getting the any values.
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-sammet-fyomv0?file=/src/components/Example2.vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>Example 2</h1>
    <input @click="send" type="button" value="Send" />
    <div class="out" v-if="successIds.length">{{ successIds }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
/*
@return
  resolve: { id: 1, success: true }
  or
  reject: { success: false }
*/
const fakeApiRequest = (id) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const success = id % 2;
      success ? resolve({ id, success }) : reject({ success });
    }, 2000);
  });
};

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      // Fetch ids
      ids: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      // Complete ids
      successIds: [],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    async send() {
      let newArr = await Promise.allSettled(
        this.ids
          .map(fakeApiRequest)
          .filter((promise) => promise.status === "fulfilled") 
          .map((promise) => promise.value)
      );
      // console.log(newArr)   -->  gets an empty array
      this.successIds.splice(0, 0, newArr);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.out {
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: #41b883;
}
</style>
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to get the `even numbers` and add them to the array which will be then displayed ?

Comment: Yes, you got it right. I’d like to display the even numbers in a new array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues:

- You are applying a `.filter` call on the promises returned by the `.map` call, but promises don't have a `status` property to filter by. You can only filter on the **resolved** values, not on the promises. So you first need to await the resolution of the `allSettled` promise before you can start filtering.
- `splice` expects the insert-values as individual arguments, not as an array. So use the spread syntax
- As you want to populate your `successIds` with `id` values, and your api returns **objects** with `id` and `success` properties, you still need to extract that `id` property from each object.

Here is a correction (I removed the vue dependecies):

```js
const fakeApiRequest = (id) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const success = id % 2;
      success ? resolve({ id, success}) : reject({ success });
    }, 200);
  });
};

const app = {
  data() {
    return {
      // Fetch ids
      ids: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      // Complete ids
      successIds: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async send() {
      const results = await Promise.allSettled(
        this.ids.map(fakeApiRequest)
      );
      const ids = results.filter((settled) => settled.status === "fulfilled")
                         .map((settled) => settled.value.id);
      this.successIds.splice(0, 0, ...ids);
      console.log(this.successIds); // for this demo only
    },
  },
};

// Mimic vue
app.methods.send.call(app.data());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only apply filters on the awaited results of `Promise.allSettled()`. So you either do just that (`await` and then apply the filters on the awaited result) or place the filters on its `then`:

Working example:

```js
const { createApp, defineComponent } = Vue;

const fakeApiRequest = (id) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const success = id % 2;
      success ? resolve({ id, success }) : reject({ success });
    }, 2000);
  });
};
const Test = defineComponent({
  template: "#test",
  data() {
    return {
      ids: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      successIds: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async send() {
      this.successIds = []
      this.successIds = await Promise.allSettled(
        this.ids.map(fakeApiRequest)
      ).then((results) =>
        results
          .filter(({ status }) => status === "fulfilled")
          .map(({ value }) => value.id)
      );
    },
  },
});
createApp({
  components: { Test },
}).mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <test />
</div>
<template id="test">
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>Example 2</h1>
    <input @click="send" type="button" value="Send" />
    <div class="out" v-if="successIds.length">{{ successIds }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Side note: you don't need to `splice` the results to keep reactivity. If you lose reactivity, you should ask a separate question about it, providing enough detail. As you can see, it works perfectly fine in my example.